# In the `import` syntax of ES6, how is a module evaluated exactly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, webpack, commonjs

Let's say we have four modules, `A`, `B`,`C` and `D`

In module `A`:

```
console.log("A evaluated")
function AClass {
  console.log("A constructor")
}
var aObj = new AClass()
export default aObj;
```

In module `B`:

```
import aObj from A
export default "B"
```

In module `C`:

```
import aObj from A
export default "C"
```

In module `D`:

```
import b from B
import c from C
import aObj from A
```

So when module `D` is evaluated, how many times will the `A evaluated` and `A constructor` be printed in the console?

Is this behavior described in **ES6 standard**? What should I do if I want a module to be evaluated ONLY ONCE no matter how many times is imported directly or indirectly? Does anyone have any ideas about this?

Comment: Just saying, you shouldn't export instances, you should always export the class - or if you only need objects, you shouldn't use classes.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks, but what should I do if I need a external global singleton instance in different modules... Maybe exporting instances is the only way..

Comment: You can use simple object literals to create singletons. No need for `class`es.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

When the `D` module is executed, the console will print this message:

```
A evaluated
A constructor
```

Which means that the `A` module was evaluated only once, even if it was imported multiple times by other modules.

The evaluation rules for `ES6 modules` is the same as for `commonjs` format:

- A module is a piece of code that is executed once it is loaded. It means that if a module is not included in the main bundle, it will not be evaluated
- Modules are singletons. If a module is imported multiple times, only a single `instance` of it exists and it is evaluated only once at load

---

The behaviour of **importing the same instance of the module** is described [HostResolveImportedModule](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-hostresolveimportedmodule) section of the ECMAScript 6 specification.
It mentions:

> This operation *(import operation)* must be idempotent if it completes normally. Each time
> it is called with a specific referencingModule, specifier pair *(import <a> from <source>)* as
> arguments it must return the same Module Record instance.

The behaviour of **single time evaluation** of the module is described in [ModuleEvaluation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-moduleevaluation), point 4 and 5 using `Evaluated` boolean flag.
Each module has `Evaluated` flag which makes sure to evaluate the module code only once.

---

Following the answer, I wrote [a more detailed post](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-module-import-twice/) with a demonstration of the double import.

Comment: Nothing in there about differently specified relative imports.   Could be seen as different sources.