# ES 6 import Vue

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, vue.js, vuejs2

I created my `service` file like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'

var service = {
    counter : 1,
    loadProducts : function(){
        return Vue.http.get('http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cqLJAlYsPm?indent=2');
    }
}

export default service
```

and I have imported it in my single component

```
<!-- src/components/ProductList.vue -->
<template>
    <table class="table table-hover product-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr v-for="product in products" track-by="id">
                <td>{{product.about}}</td>
                <td>{{product.address}}</td>
                <td>{{product.age}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</template>

<script>    
    import service from './my-service.js'

export default {
    created: function(){
        service.counter++;
        console.log(service);
        console.log('created');

        service.loadProducts().then(response => {
            this.products = response.data;
        });

    },
  data () {
    return {
        products: []
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Is this proper method to write API calls? If I import Vue in service file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
```

will this be included in my js file again? So everytime I write import Vue the my JS file would keep bloating?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I import Vue in service file [...] will this be included in my js file again? So everytime I write import Vue the my JS file would keep bloating?

If you are not [code splitting](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/), then no, the `vue` module will not be included multiple times in the same chunk, [nor will that module be initialized every time it is imported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36564901/in-the-import-syntax-of-es6-how-is-a-module-evaluated-exactly). If you are code splitting, then you need to use the [CommonsChunkPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin) to [prevent duplication](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#prevent-duplication) of the same module across multiple chunks (if that concerns you).

Comment: Excellent. My setup does have CommonsChunkPlugin.