# Do I have multiple instances of an exported constant or one when imported multiple times?

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I'm using the angular webpack starter:
https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter

and had noticed that in the [angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-3-wrap-up), they are exporting an animation as a const. If import the animation in two components and use it, do I have two instances or one in the global scope?

`import { animation } from /file`

How do the imports work?

Comment: Importing doesn't create instances, therefore you only have one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In the \`import\` syntax of ES6, how is a module evaluated exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36564901/in-the-import-syntax-of-es6-how-is-a-module-evaluated-exactly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> do I have two instances or one in the global scope

All modules are evaluated *only once* on first import. So a single instance of a module => single instance of exported members.