# Can React.context be used to share a common object?

Tags: reactjs, react-context

So I've been reading about using react context to avoid drilling of props. A basic example is has a component which provides a value which itself is kept in the Component state:

```
<ThemeContext.Provider value={this.state.shared, updateMyState}>
```

and a Consumer that uses that value.

Can I share the value of an exported list instead or should the Component which provides the Provider always refer to its state or a static value?

Here is what I mean:

file ./list:

```
export const list = [];
export const updateList = (val) => list.push(val);
```

file ./provider:

```
import Provider from './provider'
import {list, updateList} from ./list

{Provider, Consumer} = React.createContext();
export ProviderComponent = () => 
   <Provider value={list, updateList}>
      <children>
   </Provider>
}
```

Comment: If I understand what you're asking correctly — you can add functions / methods to the Provider, and then reference those in state to pass them through to the Consumer.

Comment: @Colin Are you saying that the above example is incorrect, and I should first store the reference to the list in the `ProviderComponent` ? The list object is the core of my question

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. If you're concerned about importing module multiple times creates multiple instances of list object, when you do an import like `import { a, b } from './file`, `./file` is referenced only once ([Check out this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36565293/10340970)).

I think your syntax is slightly off though, it should be

```
<Provider value={{ list, updateList }}>
```